# When breeding two purebred dog types, does it matter which parent is which breed?

Tags: dogs, breeding

For example, will there be any consistent difference between a Beagle / Cavalier King Charles Spaniel if the mom is the Beagle and the dad is the Cavalier compared to the dad being the Beagle and the mom being the Cavalier?

Comment: No it doesn't matter but I believe it is considered best practice to have the larger breed for the bitch.